# Foley - Paper Burning Sound

Tags: foley

Im currently doing a post production for a short film and we are doing some foley works right now. There is a scene in my film that there is a guy that burning an exam paper so we want to have a sound for that burning paper.

Thank you guys for answering. I will send you the DVD for my short film for one who answering this question. Just give me your address :D

Comment: How fast is the paper burning?

Comment: it is not that fast.. its slow burn of paper. The character tear the paper and put it slowly on the fire

Answer (score 4):

You have some options.  You can obviously burn a piece of paper, although that might pose a hazard if not contained.  It's fairly simple to reproduce a sound *like* it, but not exactly like.

I would take some cellophane stretch wrap and twist/fold it around, but you could also use aluminum foil or some other thin material.  I think the foil would sound too metallic, but the cellophane might work well.

Alternatively, you could use pre-recorded sounds:
http://soundbible.com/tags-burn.html
http://www.soundsnap.com/tags/burning

If you wanted to synthesize it, you could read this article: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/projects/sound/fire/

Comment: Never tried cellophane for some reason, so thanks for the tip. As for burning real paper I never got that to work. Doesn't sound like anything I associate with burning paper :)

Comment: hey guys.. email me your guys' address or anything that i can send the dvd :D thanks for helping.. khairudinalibidin@gmail.com

Comment: Is it a problem that my most upvoted answer is about how to make people think I'm burning something?

Answer (score 2):

Twist and crumble aluminum foil, plastic wrap or plastic bag very slowly so that it makes crackling sound with short transients. Not all wraps or bags work. Plastic bag might require some hard twisting and crushing before the performance to get rid of the stiffness.

I've used this for candles and as a component for very slowly burning torches, but I guess it would work for burning paper too. Obviously doesn't sound anything like small things burning, but still works :)